# How to update local repository with pull

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, git-pull

I have been working on my repository on a local branch... I finally made all the changes needed and committed then pushed to my github account.

I then went to another computer to pull that copy down to update my out of date local version... When I try and pull it, it says:

```
Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: if you are sure all changes are irelevant on this version: `git reset --hard && git pull` or `git stash && git pull && git stash apply` if you need this changes. (safer would be to commit them then pull)

Comment: The odd thing is, I have no local new commits on my other computer. It's just an out of date version kind of thing... although I'm also unsure where to put command line git stuff in visual studio 2013

Comment: @JamesT Run git bash, change current directory to the root of you project and execute command "git status" to see what files were changed since last commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says, you should either commit or undo your changes.
You can save them for letter with

```
git stash
```

when you want to reaply changes after stash, do:
git stash pop

Or you can commit them with:

```
git commit -am 'Your commit message'
```

The last option, if you do not need your changes, you can simple remove them completely:

```
git reset --hard
```

Beware that you cannot restore changes after this command.

There are analogs of these commands in [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

Comment: Thanks, it actually says "no local changes to save" so I should be able to pull at this point, right?

Comment: ahhhhh I see now, I had to close my solution in visual studio, then just work through the team explorer panel to do the pull (after git stash confirmed I had no more changes to make)